# HTTP listeners without controller in Ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, httplistener

We are integrating our Rails Web Application with several HTTP data exchange services and I plan to make one class per service in `lib` folder.

The problem is that not only we should call a service, but service can also send us HTTP requests.

I would make controllers for these services with a strong unwillingness because I want to encapsulate as more code as possible in single `*.rb` file.

Is a Ruby class able to publish HTTP listeners in Rails or to eliminate/minimize usage of Rails controller in some way?

Comment: I'd build a thin layer of controllers. If you start fighting rails, you will not win :)

Comment: Have you considered [`ActionController::Metal`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html)? It is a minimal controller for things like APIs. Removed are modules for filtering, rendering, layouts, auth tokens, caching, all the stuff you'd get in a full `ActionController::Base` stack, adding back in whatever functionality you need.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev: I would accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Paul: nah, I'm too lazy to make a full answer out of it. :)